# Power series solution to $y'+(1+x)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the power series solution for this DE.

Can't seem to find the right recursive formula though!

please help

Comment: Did you let $y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $ and sub in?

Comment: yes: got to $y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty [a_{n+2}(n+2)+a_{n+1}+a_n ]x^{n+1} + a_1 + a_0 = 0$ but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Why not just write down the solution (obvious by inspection) and expand it as a power series :)

Comment: Because that is not what the exercise asks for. it wants to let $y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming
$$ y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n\, x^n $$
you have:
$$ y'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} na_n\,x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1} x^n,\tag{1}$$
$$ (1+x)\cdot y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(a_n+a_{n-1})\,x^n,\tag{2}$$
where $a_{-1}=0$. So we have:
$$ a_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{n+1}\left(a_n+a_{n-1}\right)\tag{3} $$
as you stated, but this recurrence relation is quite hard to crack. However, notice that the original ODE is a separable differential equation, leading to:
$$ y(x) = K\cdot\exp\left(-x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right), \tag{4} $$
so, assuming $K=1$, we can compute $a_n$ by multiplying the Taylor series of $e^{-x}$ and $e^{-x^2/2}$:
$$ e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n,\qquad e^{-x^2/2}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{2^m\,m!}x^{2m},\tag{5}$$

> $$ a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k\,k!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{n-2k}}{(n-2k)!}=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k\,k!(n-2k)!}.\tag{6}$$

Comment: Is there a way to get the $a_n$ just in terms of n and not k? I'm not even sure where the k indices came from.

Comment: I do not think that $a_n$ has a "nice closed expression" in terms of $n$ only. The index $k$ comes from considering the Cauchy product of the two series in $(5)$.

Comment: Instructions on the homework are to "obtain a recursion for the coefficients $a_n$." Are you telling me my prof is being kinda tricky?

Comment: @Andrew: Absolutely not. I agree with you that the recursion is the one you found, and I found in $(3)$. I only showed, in $(6)$, that the recursion can be solved.

Comment: @Andrew Tricky? He is probably trying to make the point that you should not apply techniques blindly. There is often a better way.